# MySQL: Delete an Select Clause

Tags: mysql

Consider a table `table1` and its corresponding lookup table `table2`:

```
`table1`
columns: col1 | id
number of rows: ~2Mi

`table2`
columns: id <primary key> | col2
number of rows: ~1Mi
```

Since there are several ids in `table2` which are not being used in `table1`, they can be deleted. This can be done with the following query:

```
DELETE FROM `table2` WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT `table2`.`id` FROM `table2`
        LEFT JOIN `table1`
        ON `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`id`
        WHERE `table1`.`id` IS NULL
    ) AS p
)
```

However, this query is very slow (~100 rows per minute).

**Question**
Why this query is so slow? How to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite it as:

```
DELETE FROM `table2` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.id = `table2`.id);
```

Adding index on `table2(id)` and `table1(id)` will also help.

Comment: Amazing, ~500k rows deleted in 30secs. Mind to explain the reasoning? Why the other one was so slow, and why this one is so much faster?

Comment: @MarkMessa Checking for existance/non-existance is almost always faster when you use `EXISTS` clause than `LEFT JOIN` two big tables.